# fundamental group of complement of curve in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm interested in the fundamental group of $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^4-\mathcal{C})$, here $C$ a smooth curve without boundary(compact or noncompact).

I think by Alexlander duality I can see that $H_1(\mathbb{R}^4-\mathcal{C})$ is $0$, however I'm not sure about fundamental group. If I can prove the fundamental group is abelian, the problem is done, however I have no idea to show it, can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: You probably need some more assumptions on the curve. Is it embedded or do you allow it to have some accumulation points? If it's embedded, then $\pi_1$ will be zero for dimension reasons.

Comment: Yes we can assume it to be embedd, but why $\pi_1$ is zero?

Comment: @taiat : my intuition is as follows: for an embedded curve you may assume that the curve locally is $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$ and the path "around" it in the $x_3=x_4=0$ plane. Then you can move the path away from the curve increasing $x_3$ at will.

Comment: Every loop can be extended to a map of the disk into $\mathbb R^4$. The disk might intersect $\mathcal C$, but you can put things in general position to be disjoint (probably by Sard's theorem in some way). This works because the ambient space has high enough dimension relative to the curve and disk.

Comment: @EthanDlugie Thanks! In fact I've seen similar arguments in the book H-cobordism by Milnor, however in this book Milnor say that to move the disk, we need the dimension of total space to be 5 or higher, I'm not sure if it the assumption is necessary.